# PHP SolrClient Connection error

Tags: php, solr

I am using solr server for one of my projects. The manual import and query selection are working fine. Also I am able to get the results from the solr server.
The actual problem is, whenever I tried to update the solr server using the [PHP-SolrClient](http://php.net/manual/en/class.solrclient.php), it returns error.
The code I have used the below given query for solr updation.

```
$options = array(
'hostname' => 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx',
'login'    => '',
'password' => '',
'port'     => 8983); 
$client = new SolrClient($options);
$client->ping();
```

But the code returns the following error.

> Warning: SolrClient::ping(): Entity: line 1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found in /var/www/html/test.php on line 132 Call Stack: 0.0095 234296 1. {main}() /var/www/html/test.php:0 0.0096 237776 2. SolrClient->ping() /var/www/html/test.php:132 Warning: SolrClient::ping(): HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found in /var/www/html/test.php on line 132 Call Stack: 0.0095 234296 1. {main}() /var/www/html/test.php:0 0.0096 237776 2. SolrClient->ping() /var/www/html/test.php:132 Warning: SolrClient::ping(): ^ in /var/www/html/test.php on line 132 Call Stack: 0.0095 234296 1. {main}() /var/www/html/test.php:0 0.0096 237776 2. SolrClient->ping() /var/www/html/test.php:132 Warning: SolrClient::ping(): Xpath Error: no elements found in /var/www/html/test.php on line 132 Call Stack: 0.0095 234296 1. {main}() /var/www/html/test.php:0 0.0096 237776 2. SolrClient->ping() /var/www/html/test.php:132 Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'SolrClientException' with message ' in /var/www/html/test.php on line 132 SolrClientException: Unsuccessful ping request : Response Code 404. HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1 Cache-Control: must-revalidate,no-cache,no-store Content-Length: 300 in /var/www/html/test.php on line 132 Call Stack: 0.0095 234296 1. {main}() /var/www/html/test.php:0 0.0096 237776 2. SolrClient->ping() /var/www/html/test.php:132

Can anyone help me to find out what causes the error?

Comment: let us know what you have on line 132 in your `test.php` script :)

Comment: @mitkosoft line number 132 is having `$client->ping();`

Comment: Indeed, I don't know why do you need such a client? The Solr http api is very enough and you can set its output in many forms such as Ajax, xml, php arrays, etc and using `file_get_content` every thing will be handy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please specify the collection path in the options

```
$options = array(
'hostname' => 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx',
'login'    => '',
'password' => '',
'port'     => 8983,
'path'     => 'solr/<collection name>'
);
```

Comment: If I ping an inexistent core it throws a warning AND an exception. Does anybody know how to prevent the warning?? Thanks!!